# Custom directive not working whenever moving to other page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple setcalender directive on one page and it works fine. However, if I go to another page and then come back, the calender doesn't show up anymore. Below is the directive code. Am I missing cleaning up scope before rendering or anything?

HTML Code

```
<div>
    <label>Date</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="date" setcalendar>
</div>
```

Custom Directive

```
angular.module("myapp").directive("setcalendar", function () {
    debugger;
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(attrs.datepicker, function () {
                $(element).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                    mode: 'single',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage: "Content/images/Cal.png",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    class:"calendar",
                    onSelect: function (dateText) {
                        var expression = attrs.ngModel + " = " +
                           "'" + dateText + "'";
                        scope.$apply(expression);

                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post your code with html

Comment: @ThanhTùng I have posted html code.

Comment: Don't use jquery's datepicker, use a [native one](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepickerPopup)